# Open url into android app

Tags: android

currently i'm building blog/news portal app based on web version in android, i want if someone search a query on google/bing or another search engine in android browser and found my web `www.newsportal.com/this-is-article-slug`  then browser tell there are choices to open it, open in browser itself or open on my `newsportal app` instead, then my app catch my link `www.newsportal.com/this-is-article-slug`, extract this slug `this-is-article-slug` then open new activity, search the article via API and done. I tried read some reference like `http://developer.android.com/training/sharing/receive.html` but I confuse where do i start,, 
Thanks for your help..

Comment: use to deeplinking

Answer (score 0):

Open search result in application you need to add  in your activity tag in Manifest.xml like below

```
<intent-filter>
   <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

   <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
   <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
   <data
       android:host="your host"
       android:scheme="your scheme" />
</intent-filter>
```

And handle result in in your activity like

```
 Intent intent = getIntent();
 Uri data = intent.getData();
 String action = intent.getAction();

 if (Intent.ACTION_VIEW.equalsIgnoreCase(action) && data != null) {
     if (data.getScheme().equals("your scheme")
                    && data.getAuthority().equals("your host")) {
            }
        }
```